# Relation between infimum and supremum

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is an open set. Does the inequality
$$
|\inf_{\Omega}\,f|\leq C\,\sup_{\Omega}|f|,
$$
hold for some constant $C>0$?

Indeed, since $\inf_{\Omega}\,f\leq |f|$, we have $\inf_{\Omega}\,f\leq\sup_{\Omega}|f|$. If the above inequality is true, can somebody please help me to how to proceed from now.

Thanks.

Comment: For bounded functions $\inf\limits_ \Omega f = \inf\limits_{\Omega_{-}} f = \inf\limits_{\Omega_{-}} (-(-f))=-\sup\limits_{\Omega_{-}}|f| $. 

So, $|\inf\limits_ \Omega f| = \sup\limits_{\Omega_{-}}|f| \leqslant \sup\limits_{\Omega}|f| $

Comment: Thanks. But can you please explain what is $\Omega_-?$

Comment: Thanks. I hope $\Omega_-=\{f(x)<0\}\cap\Omega$. Yes, I wrote bounded function now in the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For positive functions sentence is obvious, so let $\Omega=\Omega_{-} \cup \Omega_{+}$, where $f\lt 0$ on $\Omega_{-}\ne \emptyset$. Now if $f$ is not bounded from below, then same will be for $|f|$ from above, so assume $f$ is  bounded from below.

In considered case $A=\inf\limits_ \Omega f = \inf\limits_{\Omega_{-}} f = \inf\limits_{\Omega_{-}} (-(-f))=-\sup\limits_{\Omega_{-}}|f| $.

So, $|\inf\limits_ \Omega f| = \sup\limits_{\Omega_{-}}|f| \leqslant \sup\limits_{\Omega}|f| $